# Не получается вводить строку при работе со структурами

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

Задача следующая. Нужно с помощью структуры ввести ФИО студентов, год рождения, год поступления в ВУЗ и оценки по экзаменам. Вывести студентов, фамилия которых начинается с буквы A, и их оценки.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct famA {
    char fio[100];
    int yearbirth, yearpost;
    int matan, rus, op;
} round[3];

int main() 
{
    int i;
    puts("Vvedite dannye o studentah");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        puts("FIO: ");
        gets(round[i].fio);
        printf("\nYear of birth: ");
        scanf_s("%i", &round[i].yearbirth);
        printf("\nYear of post: ");
        scanf_s("%i", &round[i].yearpost);
        printf("\nGrade matan: ");
        scanf_s("%i", &round[i].matan);
        printf("\nGrade rus: ");
        scanf_s("%i", &round[i].rus);
        printf("\nGrade OP: ");
        scanf_s("%i", &round[i].op);
    } //ввод данных о студентах
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (round[i].fio[0] == 'A') {
            puts(round[i].fio);
            printf("\nmatan = %i \nrus = %i OP = %i", 
                round[i].fio, round[i].matan, round[i].rus, round[i].op);
        }
    }
    _getch();
}
```

У меня все ОК, за исключением одного - ФИО можно ввести только один раз (в первый), а потом он пишет "FIO: ", но ввести не дает, переключает сразу на год рождения. 
[image: FIO:]

Среда VS 2015.

Comment: а flushall() пробовали или что-то аналогичное?

Comment: @pavel пробовал, все то же самое :(

Comment: если вы точно делаете flush перед чтением фамилии, то попробуйте после  scanf_s("%i", &round[i].op); прочитать строку gets - ом. Но это костыль.

Comment: А если `gets` заменить на честный `scanf_s`?

Comment: @pavel Да, комбинация flushall+scanf_s+gets выдает нужный результат. Только теперь интересно, почему. 

Теперь осталось разобраться, почему выводит только последнюю фамилию, начинающуюся на букву A.

Comment: ну почему как раз понятно, scanf_s читает только число, gets читает до конца строки, а scanf_s в строке оставляет перевод). В выводе проблемы не вижу, посмотрите отладчиком что именно прочитано.

Comment: @VladD я не предлагал, так как по логике ФИО может (и должно) содержать пробелы.

Comment: @pavel: Хм, и правда. То есть scanf не подходит. Консольный ввод/вывод в C/C++ — это что-то запредельное.

Comment: @Назарий: Ну пройдитесь под отладчиком, посмотрите, что в какой переменной содержится. Может быть, лучше читать так: (1) читаете целую строку, (2) вытаскиваете из неё значение. По крайней мере не будет проблем с контролем того, кто читает конец строки, а кто нет.

Comment: @pavel как оказалось, выводится не хочет только первая фамилия. Странно.
Убрал условие из вывода, все строки выводятся.